# Auto-renew SSL certificate using Certbot under docker with nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I'm having difficulties to set up automatic renewal of SSL certificates with certbot in Docker. 
Here is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;

    auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 1440m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384";

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        auth_basic off;
        allow all;
        root /etc/letsencrypt;
    }
}
```

Then my docker-compose file:

```
services:
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"

volumes:
  database:
  app:
```

and when I run the containers I get this error in Certbot container:

```
Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: standalone). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
  Domain: example.com
  Type:   unauthorized
  Detail: xyz: Invalid response from https://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/xyz: 404
```

What's wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize the certbot command to generate a certificate for your specific domain name. Something like this (not tested myself) :

```
command: certonly --webroot -w /var/www/certbot --force-renewal --email {email} -d {domain} --agree-tos
```

Taken from this tutorial : https://www.programonaut.com/setup-ssl-with-docker-nginx-and-lets-encrypt/ but you can find many other examples